# Move element in array and rerender

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I need to move one element of the array down when pressing the "down" button and make a rerender

```
const Test = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

  const array_move = (arr, old_index, new_index) => {
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
      var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
      while (k--) {
        arr.push(undefined);
      }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
  };

  const down = () => {
    setArr(array_move(arr, 1, 2));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mt-20 p-10">
        {arr.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i} className="list-none">
            <p>{item}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={down}>down</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

In this case the array changes but does not rerender

Comment: Do not use index as the key. That is probably why re-render doesn't happen, because the elements have the same key. Use a uniquely-identifiable property of the item as the key: in this case it could be the `item` itself.

Comment: I tried that, it still re-render doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.slice` mutates the original array, which is something you don't want to do. Instead, clone the array instead (you can perform a shallow clone using `[...arr]`, and also take advantage of functional updates:

```js
const array_move = (arr, old_index, new_index) => {
  // Clone the array
  const clonedArr = [...arr];
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      clonedArr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  clonedArr.splice(new_index, 0, clonedArr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return clonedArr;
};

const down = () => {
  // Use functional updates
  setArr((prevArr) => array_move(prevArr, 1, 2));
};
```

Moreover, you should avoid using indices as `key`: use a uniquely identifiable info, in this case, `item` itself as the key.

See working example on CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit angry-bohr-dj9s07]